# Sorting by connected column from another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities:

```
public class Garden implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1198096323173371453L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer number;
    @Column(name = "plot_number", nullable = false)
    private Integer plotNumber;
    @Column(name = "person_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int personId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
}

@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6257724189464155057L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_sequence", sequenceName = "person_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
}
```

I am trying make sort on backend by columns. For sorting I use

final SpecificationUtil gardenSpecification = new SpecificationUtil<>();

```
    final List<Specification<Garden>> searchSpecification = gardenSpecification.createSearchSpecificationRaw(request);

    final Specification<Garden> specificationResult = searchSpecification.stream().reduce(null, Specification::and);
    Sort.Direction direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
    if (request.getOrderDirection().equals("desc")) {
        direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
    }

    return gardenDataService.findAll(specificationResult, Sort.by(direction, request.getOrderColumn()));



public List<Specification<T>> createSearchSpecificationRaw(DataGridRequest request) {

    final List<Specification<T>> specifications = new ArrayList<>();

    if (request.getSearchColumns() != null && !request.getSearchColumns().isEmpty()) {
        for (ColumnSearch search : request.getSearchColumns()) {

            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(search.getSearchValue())) {
                continue;
            }

            specifications.add(create(search.getColumnName(), search.getSearchValue()));
        }
    }

    return specifications;
}

/**
 * create specification
 *
 * @param columnKey
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
private Specification<T> create(String columnKey, String value) {

    final GenericSpecificationFactory<T> specificationFactory = new GenericSpecificationFactory<>();
    return specificationFactory.createLike(columnKey, value);

}
```

when I sort by column in Garden, sorting is OK. But when I want sort by lastName I get error:

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property lastName found for type Garden!

Can you help me how the best make sorting on connected column from another entity.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to add sorting by `"person.lastName"`?

Comment: What is `GenericSpecificationFactory` ? Show us `createLike` method